# How can i add || in true or false. I mean TRUE || TRUE : FALSE?

Tags: c#

```
public string AddressPastDueAgeEndorseList(string RecordAddr1, string RecordAddr2, string RecordAddr3, string RecordAddr4)
{
    string Addr1, Addr2, Addr3, Addr4;

    Addr1 = (true) ? RecordAddr1 : RecordAddr1;
    Addr2 = (true) ? RecordAddr2 : RecordAddr2;
    Addr3 = (true) ? RecordAddr3 : RecordAddr3;
    Addr4 = (true) ? RecordAddr4 : RecordAddr4;
    Addr1 = (true) ? Addr1 = "NULL" : Addr1;
    Addr1 = (true) ? Addr1 = "." : Addr1;
    return AddressPastDueAgeEndorseList(RecordAddr1, RecordAddr2, RecordAddr3, RecordAddr4);
}
```

i want like this:

```
Addr1 = (true) ? (Addr1 == "NULL" ||  Addr1 == ".") : (Addr1);
```

and to Addr2, Addr3 and Addr4

instead of:

```
Addr1 = (true) ? Addr1 = "NULL" : Addr1;
Addr1 = (true) ? Addr1 = "." : Addr1;
```

but the error occurs and says:

> type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'bool' and string.

I need to return a string value in my function.

Comment: Please update your question to show five different values of `RecordAddr1` (including `null`, "", "NULL", "." and something else) and the values you expect `Addr1` to have for each of those `RecordAddr1` values. That will help us identify what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Please provide the five different inputs and outputs that I requested. Your question is very confusing otherwise.

Comment: Your use of `(true)` is a bit weird. If you write `string Addr1 = "XXX"; Addr1 = (true) ? Addr1 = "NULL" : Addr1;` this is 100% the same as writing `string Addr1 = "NULL";`. What do you think the code means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = a ? b : c;
```

`x`, `b`, `c` must be the same type, and `a` should be a boolean.

`(Addr1 == "NULL" || Addr1 == ".")` is a boolean as it is either true or false but `Addr` is a string

so if the condition is true it will be returning a boolean otherwise a string. that is returning 2 different types. while both return types must be the same type.

As Addr1 is a string, so I persume you are trying to return a string, something like:

```
Addr1 = Addr1 == null || Addr1 == "." ? "Something" : Addr1
```

Comment: what should i put on instead of "Something"?

Comment: @ReybenVillanueva the value in case `Addr1 == "NULL" || Addr1 == "." ` is true